# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file plzz help me find out whats the error?

Tags: parsing, syntax

  0){

                             while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))

                             {    
                                 $Name=$row['Name'];
                                  $Link=$row['Link'];

              ?>
- ">

    0){

                               while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res))

                               {    
                                   $submenu=$row['submenu'];


                ?>
  - 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please share a bigger snippet of code. This error usually happens when there is a typing mistake or not closing php tags. Make sure your `<?php ?>` tags are opening and closing correctly and check if you are using shorthand tags like this `<? } ?>` If you are using it please avoid that. Also make sure that you are not mixing PHP opening and closing tags with `}?>` make sure there is a space between php opening and closing tags.